# Compute the number of points inside a circle with given radius for all points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

My input will be a list of x and y coordinates, those indicate the pixels on the picture. I will have a given radius r. For each pixel, I need to compute how many other pixels are inside the circle within the radius r. And I have to do this for all the points I have.

I understand that the brute force way to do this will be compare all other point to see if x^2+y^2 <= r^2. The complexity would be O(n^2). I am wondering if there's any approach that I can reduce the complexity to O(nlogn) or O(n)?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  Can you clarify?  Perhaps provide some examples to show what you mean.

Comment: I would first iterate once keeping track of the smallest and largest x,y value thus computing the bounding box: from the aspect ratio you can already cull a bunch of points are not being inside a circle. I would only then do a second pass to compare the squared distance of each point from the centre of the bounding box against the squared radius (avoiding sqrt). Do know what tha is, O(n*2) ? If you could get away with image processing/OpenCV: I would apply a circular mask with the given radius to cut out points, then count connected components on the points that are left (maybe dilate if req.)

Comment: You let a confusion between *pixels* and *points*. If you truly ask to count pixels, the count is the same for every center and your question does not make sense. So I assume that you actually mean one of 1) to count the *black* pixels in neighborhoods in a digital image or 2) to count the near-neighbors of points in a list. Please clarify, these are two very different problems.

Comment: Second problem: what is meant by O(n²) when we don't know what n is ?

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical answer is the area of the circle: Area = PI * r**2, though this includes partial pixels. To get the count of full pixels only, you will need to traverse an axis (x) and get the height of the other axis (y) at each point (rounded down). Do this for a quarter of the circle then multiple by 4. I'm assuming the entire circle is in the picture.

I think the complexity is O(n) based on the circle radius.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the plane into a grid with each cell having a width equal to the diameter of the circle and assign your points into bins for each cell in the grid. You can implement this as a hashmap/dictionary where the key is the top-left corner of the grid cell and the value is a list of points in the cell. Iterate through your list of points, work out which grid cell it's in and add to the appropriate list.

A circle with radius r can overlap at most 4 grid cells. Now you can iterate over the point list again and for each point you will only need to check the points in the grid cells overlapping the circle centred on the point.

This will reduce the number of checks you need to do but it is still O(n^2) in the pathological case where all points are with r of each other. To further optimize the algorithm, store a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) in each grid cell. Each node in the quadtree (the top node being the grid cell) stores a count of the number of points in the node and has up to 4 sub-nodes (empty nodes are not stored), the leaf nodes containing individual points. To test the points in a node against your point, first check if the entire node is within r of the point, if so you can count all the points without checking them individually. If not recurse into the sub-nodes that overlap the circle until you reach individual points to test or you get down to sub-nodes that lie entirely within or outside the circle.

The performance of these algorithms will be highly dependent on the distribution of your points.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is to count the points at maximum distance R to every point of a list of N points, you can use a kD-tree for acceleration.

With some care you can achieve a running time O(N Log N) for the setup of the tree, then hope for a query time of O(Log N + K) for counting, where K is the average number of neighbors.

This still makes a total of O(N Log N + KN). :-(